# How to get attribute value from XML in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am developing a framework, where I need to get the value of the attribute from a line(string) given string of attribute in C#.
Example:Here is the XML
`<av:Button Name="btn_1" Width="80" Height="25" x:Uid="btn_1" av:Canvas.Left="168.1" av:Canvas.Top="95.1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">My Button Content</av:Button>`

When input is Name, it should return btn_1.
When input is Width, it should return 80.

PS: I have implemented this using some hard-coded positions of words, but it fails sometime.
-TIA

Answer (score 1):

I would use Linq to XML. It's very easy to use

```
        String MyXml = "<av:Button Name="btn_1" Width="80" Height="25" x:Uid="btn_1" av:Canvas.Left="168.1" av:Canvas.Top="95.1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">My Button Content</av:Button>";

        XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        mngr.AddNamespace("av", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, mngr, null, XmlSpace.None);

        XmlTextReader txtReader = new XmlTextReader(MyXml, XmlNodeType.Element, parserContext);

        var doc = XElement.Load(txtReader);

        var name = doc.Attribute("Name").Value;
        var width = doc.Attribute("Width").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks James,
But I am unable to get x:Uid, Canvas.Left etc.
Can you please make it bit generic, I mean handle Namespaces properly.